# 1 Thess 5:9 vs Romans 5:9 - is this the same wrath?

Tags: revelation, romans, eschatology, 1-thessalonians

> 9For God has not destined us for wrath, but to obtain salvation
> through our Lord Jesus Christ,

This passage talks about day of the Lord so the "wrath" is God's wrath.

Based on the text, can we know the following wrath is same as day of the Lord wrath?

Romans 5:9

> 9Since, therefore, we have now been justified by his blood, much more
> shall we be saved by him from the wrath of God.

Based on this passage

Rev 2:10

> 10Do not fear what you are about to suffer. Behold, the devil is about
> to throw some of you into prison, that you may be tested, and for ten
> days you will have tribulation. Be faithful unto death, and I will
> give you the crown of life.

it seems Jesus does not guarantee Christians protection from Satan's wrath ... but I would like proof based on other uses of the word "wrath" and its context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a complete list of the all the 36 occurrences of ὀργή (orgé) in the NT, see https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_3709.htm

The uses of ὀργή (orgé = wrath) in the NT can be most simply divided as follows:

1. human emotion of wrath which is condemned as uncontrolled rage at fellow humans: Eph 4:31, Col 3:8, 1 Tim 2:8, Mark 3:5, James 1:19
2. Anger of human governments against those who commit illegal acts, Rom 13:4.
3. Anger of God in punishing past and present generations of sinners, Rom 1:18, 12:19, 1 Thess 2:16, Heb 3:11, 4:3.
4. "*Wrath of God's future judgement specifically qualified as punitive*" (BDAG), Luke 3:7, 21:23, Mark 3:7, 1 Thess 1:10, 5:9, Rom 2:5, 8, 3:5, 4:15, 5:9, 9:22, 12:19, Eph 2:3, 5:6, Col 3:6, Rev 6:16, 17, 11:18, 14:10, 16:19, 19:15, etc.

Therefore, the answer to the OP's question is, "Yes" - the instances of ὀργή (orgé) in Rom 5:9 and 1 Thess 5:9 both refer to "*Wrath of God's future judgement specifically qualified as punitive*".

More specifically, the text of Rom 5:9 is (BLB):

> Therefore, since we have now been justified by His blood, how much
> more shall we be saved from wrath through Him!

Note the tenses of the two verbs:

- δικαιωθέντες = (having been justified) Aorist Participle passive; ie, we have been justified
- σωθησόμεθα = (we will be saved) future indicative passive; ie, we will be saved in the future

Thus, the force of Rom 5:9 is simple - God's past justification of us enables our future salvation from God's eschatological wrath (= punishment)